# How to get Line Count in MS Word?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I am using Word Interop to calculate the number of lines present in a Table [Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.cell?view=word-pia).
The Cell in question is shown below (Special characters enabled for clarity).
[image]

The number of new line characters present in the text are 3. However, due to the length of the second text it is extended into a second line resulting in 4 lines.

The following code which calculates the number of new line characters returns 3.

```
input.Count(x => x == '\r'); //Result:3
```

The Word Count tool provided by Word provides the correct result, 4 lines.
[image]

The following code uses the Cell.Range property to access the ComputeStatistics function which the Word Count tool uses. However the result of the function call is always 0.

```
lines = cell.Range.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines); //Result:0
```

I tried iterating over all Paragraphs within the Range, calling the ComputeStatistics function for each Paragraph.Range separately while calculating a running total. The first paragraph returns a value of 1 but all subsequent calls return the value 0.

How do I get the value of line count shown by the Word Count tool?
What, if any, alternatives exist to get an accurate Line Count in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about the end-of-cell marker seems to interfere with the statistics. This worked for me in VBA though:

```vb
Dim c As Cell, rng As Range

Set c = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1)
Set rng = c.Range
rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

Debug.Print rng.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines)  '4
```

[image]

Comment: I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: It works! Gotta love Stackoverflow for these type of expert answers. Thanks a bunch Mr.Williams! Now, my solution will remain clean due to this rather simple implementation.

Comment: I have created a Pull request to have the official documentation changed to reflect this. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/pull/1471

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation code in C#

```
private int GetNumberOfLinesInRange(Cell cell)
{
     int lines = -1;
     Range cellRange = cell.Range;

     //Range decreased by 1 
     //to omit the end of cell marker from the calculation which 
     //interferes with the ComputeStatistics result
     cellRange.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1); 

     lines = cellRange.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines);
     return lines;
}
```